# Ember.js: How can I access records from a fixture in a view after they have been fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Consider the code below:

```
App.ChartView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var scope = this;

        scope.get("controller.model.electricity", 1).map(function(record) {
            console.log(record._data);
        });

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("--");

            scope.get("controller.model.electricity", 1).map(function(record) {
                console.log(record._data);
            });
        }, 1);

        $.plot($("#chart"), [{
            label: "bla",
            data: [[1, 1], [1, 2]]
        }, {
            label: "bla2",
            data: [[2, 1], [2, 2]]
        }], {
            yaxis: {
                max: 10
            }
        });
    },
    initChart: function() {
        console.log("---");

        this.get("controller.model.electricity", 1).map(function(record) {
            console.log(record._data);
        });
    }.observes("controller.model.electricity.isLoaded", 1)
```

The first `console.log(record._data)` is not reached. The second `console.log(record._data)` inside the `window.setTimeOut()` function logs the desired data while the `console.log()` inside the `observer()` function `initChart()` which observes if the data is loaded also isn't reached. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The 
**didInsertElement**
gets Called when the element of the view has been inserted into the DOM or after the view was re-rendered.

The **Init method** is invoked automatically when a new instance is created .

Try using the Init function to get data.

Comment: Hi prashanth, Thanks for your answer, in the init() function the controller is still null so it gives an 'cannot read property 'map' of null' error.